# RestClient: how to correctly unmarshall text/xml response

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, rest, spring-webclient

I need to consume an external REST API that returns not a json (application/json), but an xml (`text/xml` to be precise, not application/xml). I'm using the new `RestClient` introduced in Spring Boot 3.2.

This is an example of the data that the external api returns:

```xml
<Player>
  <NAME>Someone</NAME>
</Player>
```

I can't change the response type based on the Accept header, the external api only returns stuff with the `text/xml` type. Of course, as it's an external api, I don't have a say in what is the return type.

I created this class:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement(name = "Player")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PlayerModel {
    @XmlElement(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
}
```

And I tried this:

```java
RestClient restClient = RestClient.create();

PlayerModel result = restClient.get()
            .uri(url)
            .retrieve()
            .body(PlayerModel.class);
```

But this crashed everything, as everytime I called the external api, it said that it didn't understand how to unmarshall something of type `text/xml`.

Then I read from [spring docs about REST Clients](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/integration/rest-clients.html) about `HTTP Message Conversion`. There it said that there are many `HttpMessageConverter`, and that each one has a default media type that it supports. I guess that whatever RestClient is using by default doesn't support by default the type `text/xml`, so I decided to use one of the suggested. I was between `MarshallingHttpMessageConverter` and `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter`.

With `MarshallingHttpMessageConverter` I had trouble, as I wanted to use an Unmarshaller made from `JAXBContext` (there will be code about this further down), which creates an Unmarshaller from `jakarta.xml.bind.Unmarshaller`. However, when creating a `MarshallingHttpMessageConverter`, if you try to pass this Unmarshaller to it (it accepts both an Unmarshaller and a Marshaller), it fails because it expects an Unmarshaller from `org.springframework.oxm.Unmarshaller`. I don't know about that, but maybe what I want is close to this.

As that didn't quite work, I used `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter`, like so:

```java
RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder()
            .messageConverters(converters -> {
                MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter();
                converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(List.of(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_XML));
                converters.add(converter);
            })
            .build();
```

Now it doesn't explode, but when checking the variable `PlayerModel result`, the `name` is null, meaning it didn't catch it (should be `Someone`, but is `null`).

Lastly I resorted to catching it as a `String`, instead of a `PlayerModel`, and use a JAXB created Unmarshaller to unmarshall the xml content of the string into a playerModel:

```java
RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder()
            .messageConverters(converters -> {
                MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter();
                converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(List.of(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_XML));
                converters.add(converter);
            })
            .build();

String result = restClient.get()
            .uri(url)
            .retrieve()
            .body(String.class);

PlayerModel playerModel;

try {
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(PlayerModel.class).createUnmarshaller();
    playerModel = (PlayerModel) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(result));
} catch (JAXBException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

return playerModel;
```

This works, but I want a better way to do it. I know there must be one, but I already used a lot of time for this. Maybe with some Bean configuration, or maybe with another HttpMessageConverter, or another Unmarshaller. The objective is this:

```java
PlayerModel result = restClient.get()
            .uri(url)
            .retrieve()
            .body(PlayerModel.class);
```

I'd appreciate any help I can get. Thanks :)))

Answer (score 0):

Despairing over the same question, on solutionfall I fell into this trap: `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter`. Dependency hell at its finest: with Spring bypassing the compiler, missing classes popped up again and again at run-time. :-( Finally one of them lacked a method and when I tried an older version, another method. @*!%&@!

So I explored up and down Spring Boot’s class hierarchies, and came up with this solution, specially 3<sup>rd</sup> and if needed, 5<sup>th</sup> line:

```java
RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder()
    .baseUrl(…)
    .messageConverters(converters -> converters.add(new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter()))
    .build();
restClient.head().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
return HttpServiceProxyFactory
    .builderFor(RestClientAdapter.create(restClient))
    .build()
    .createClient(….class);
```

Even if XML is stodgy, it’s still a standard. I’m really surprised that this doesn’t work out of the box (after all that server cleanly set the mime type.) And at least this should be documented in the `RestClient` javadoc!