# Deserialize text json with Rest Client in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, client

I'm having trouble with the response of an external REST API and rest clients from Spring. I'm currently using the new (+3.2.0 if I'm not mistaken) "Rest Client", but I'll also accept answers that solve the problem for "Web Client", if it applies and you coudn't find an answer for the new Rest Client.

Simply put, I make a request to an external REST API that returns a body. The content-type header reads:

```
application/json; charset=utf-8
```

The body itself actually isn't your normal json that the Web Client or Rest Client would (I suppose) be able to deseralize without problem. It seems to be a text json, even though that media type in itself doesn't exist. An example of the response body:

```
"{\"Code\":\"123-456\",\"Number\":1}"
```

Let me reiterate that that is the literal response, not this:

```json
{
  "Code": "123-456",
  "Number": 1
}
```

I tried this and didn't work:

```java
{
  Object response = restClient.post()
    .uri(url)
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .body(request)
    .retrieve()
    .body(ApiResponse.class);
}
```

I also tried:

```java
{
  Object response = restClient.post()
    .uri(url)
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .body(request)
    .retrieve()
    .body(String.class);
}
```

Both of these throw the same error, they break at the `.body(...) part`. I've also tried `.toEntity(...)`, and it breaks there too. I'll just show the one for the first one:

```
Error while extracting response for type [com.example.test.models.ApiResponse] and content type [application/json;charset=utf-8]

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.String` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
at [Source: (jdk.internal.net.http.ResponseSubscribers$HttpResponseInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
```

My guess is that, because the response's content-type header is `application/json`, it expects a json, that starts with `{`. However, the response starts with `"`, because, like I said, it's not a normal json, it's a json in string literal format. Thus the `Cannot deserialize value of type 'java.lang.String' from Object value (token 'JsonToken.START_OBJECT')`.

I managed to make it work changing to "Rest Template" and doing something else, but I don't want to do that. I want to make this work with Rest Client/Web Client.

Pls help, I have no idea what else to do. Also, is there any reason why someone would do this intentionally? I mean, making the response a json string instead of a normal json. I wouldn't be writting this right now if this external REST API responded with a normal json (i would guess).

Edit: I'm using the default Rest Client with the default Message Converters.

Edit 2: I investigated a bit and I know what was throwing this error. I will leave it in an answer below. However, there's still a problem, being more on par with the title of the question. I'll leave it there as well.

Edit 3: I'm following this in another question: [Deserializing Json from String with Rest Client and Object Mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78029034/deserializing-json-from-string-with-rest-client-and-object-mapper)

Comment: Is Jackson on the classpath? (So that jackson can be used as a message converter.)  Also, try setting the _accept_ header to MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.

Comment: If the response really starts and ends with double quotes, then this seems like a bug - `"{\"Code\":\"123-456\",\"Number\":1}"` is valid json string and you should be able to parse it to `java.lang.String`. **But**, the errors you are getting makes me believe the actual response is `{\"Code\":\"123-456\",\"Number\":1}`, which is not a valid json and ideally should be fixed from the maintainers of the API.

Comment: @AndrewS I do have jackson, and I recently even added `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` to the RestClient message converters, but nothing. I also have the accept header like you mentioned. But no luck, I still get the exception mentioned. Maybe it isn't picking up the message coverter right, like you said.

Comment: @Chaosfire the response "{\"Code\":\"123-456\",\"Number\":1}" is correct. I too think I should be able to at least parse it to String, but no. My guess is that it has to do with the content type expected. I had something like this with xml, the response content type was "text/xml" and the body was a string xml. In that case, I had to add a message converter that supported "text/xml", and then I was able to parse it to String (not my class though) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77663426/restclient-how-to-correctly-unmarshall-text-xml-response

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this external API was returning **500** instead of **200**. That triggered an error handler that I had, and I didn't know. The thing is that I was able to inspect, within the error handler, the error message. With that, I was able to solve this 1st problem.

As it turns out, this external API was expecting the request body to be a **string**, not an **object**.

Expected this:

```java
String responseString = restClient.post()
    .uri(url)
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .body(request.toJsonString()) // <-- method to convert it to a json string that I created
//...
```

Not this:

```java
String responseString = restClient.post()
    .uri(url)
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .body(request) // <-- original object from ApiRequest class
//...
```

So yeah, sorry for wasting your time. This API is poorly documented and suffers some questionable design choices.

Comment: Create your own constructor manually and annotate it with @JsonCreator. Note that the error specifies that no constructor having String parameters exist, so you have to create a constructor that takes a String as input and deserializes it to ApiResponse Object.

Comment: I've removed the additional question from this answer, as answers are strictly for solutions only. But you can ask a new question, and link to this answer or the question above, if that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t been able to try the solution but it might give you ideas :

Have you tried using `bodyToMono(String.class)` instead? You can follow it by `.block()` even if it’s generally not recommended.

Then convert your responseString to a json using jackson like :

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

// ...

String responseString = restClient.post()
    .uri(url)
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .body(request)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(String.class)
    .block();

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode responseJson = objectMapper.readTree(responseString);
```

Comment: @Kyyel Hi man, thanks for the response. I'm currently using Rest Client. In Rest Client, the equivalent of Web Client's `.bodyToMono(String.class)` is `.body(String.class)` (or `.toEntity(String.class)`), so it's the same. I also planned to get the response as a String, and then use the ObjectMapper, but my code explodes at `.body(String.class)`, so I can't get to it :(